# How to inject an environment variable into the context of new started thread?

Tags: c#

I want to inject a environment variable to a new created thead so that the processes which will be started inside of the thread can see this variable.

Till now it does not work, I tried it like this

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.EnvironmentVariables["foo"] = "bar";
applicationThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(scanner.start));
applicationThread.Start();
```

But the processes which will be started inside of my thread do not see the environment variable "foo"

Thanks

Comment: How are you starting the processes? How are you passing `startInfo` into `scanner.start`?

Comment: Thats my question. Is it possible to add my startInfo to a Thread so that it will be used for all coming sub processes / threads?

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Start` has an overload taking an `Object` parameter. You can pass your variable this way.

From MSDN (`Thread.Start(Object)` method documentation):

> Causes the operating system to change the state of the current
>   instance to ThreadState.Running, and optionally supplies an object
>   containing data to be used by the method the thread executes.

You should be able to use it like this:

```
applicationThread.Start(startInfo.EnvironmentVariables["foo"]);
```